# Determine if current screen has visible navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa, singleton, uinavigationbar

I have a singlton object. Is there any simple way to determine if current screen contains a navigation bar within singlton methods?

The singleton is UIView subclass. It's designed for showing prorgess activity, e.g. network exchange. It looks like black rectangle dropping down from top and hiding when the work is done. Why singleton? It's easy to call it from any place of code

The followed snippet is showing the initialization of activity singleton and published here just for better understaning my idea.

```
-(void) showUpdatingView:(NSString *) msg {
    [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
    activity = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];
    activity.frame = CGRectMake(5, 10, 22, 22);
    labelView = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 10, 22)] autorelease];
    labelView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    labelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    labelView.text = msg;
    [self addSubview:activity];
    [self addSubview:labelView];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.alpha = 0.7;
}
```

The activity can be called by

```
[[ActivitySingleton getInstance] showUpdatingView:@"Getting data."];
```

it's not all.
The singleton is being created in AppDelegate object and the view is added to

```
    inlineActivity = [[CHInlineActivityView alloc] initView];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:inlineActivity];
```

I know it may look crazy. But when I was designing it seemed to me reasonable

Comment: You certainly don't need a singleton to accomplish this. Just to clarify, do you want to determine whether there's a navigation controller, or whether there's a navigation bar? You might want to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Current screen means current viewcontroller? Is yes than it has property navigationController.navigationBar

Comment: @George: If I have the piece containing a numeric candle then surely I can say the age :D .

Comment: Will this help you a bit? int n = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] - 2;
if (n >= 0)
    if ([(UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:n]navigationItem].backBarButtonItem == nil)
        // Do your thing....

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya I am lying on the floor:))) It is a rectangle cake:)

Comment: I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question - now extended

Answer (score 1):

if you have all in one navigationController:

`BOOL navHidden = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigatonBarHidden;`

---

if you don't it is a bit harder.. you could check the window's subviews and see if you can find a `UINavigationBar`

```
id navbar = [self.window firstSubviewOfKind:[UINavigationBar class] withTag:NSNotFound];
BOOL navHidden = navbar == nil;


@implementation NSView (findSubview)

- (NSArray *)findSubviewsOfKind:(Class)kind withTag:(NSInteger)tag inView:(NSView*)v {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(kind==nil || [v isKindOfClass:kind]) {
        if(tag==NSNotFound || v.tag==tag) {
            [array addObject:v];
        }
    }

    for (id subview in v.subviews) {
        NSArray *vChild = [self findSubviewsOfKind:kind withTag:tag inView:subview];
        [array addObjectsFromArray:vChild];
    }

    return array;
}

#pragma mark - 

- (NSView *)firstSubviewOfKind:(Class)kind withTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    NSArray *subviews = [self findSubviewsOfKind:kind withTag:tag inView:self];
    return subviews.count ? subviews[0] : nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, Daij-Djan. My app is not completely in single navigationController. I'll try your solution and the will let you know if it's working.